# Should I load eTeX and/or fixltx2e by default

Tags: best-practices, e-tex, fixltx2e

So, inspired by [Fixing LaTeX2e](http://www.texdev.net/2014/12/28/fixing-latex2e/) I've been wondering: Should I be loading `fixltx2e` and/or `eTeX` by default?

Typically I start my documents as

```
%Page layout here
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt]{article}
```

Should this be changed to

```
\RequirePackage{etex}
\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}
%Page layout here
\documentclass[letterpaper, 11pt]{article}
```

Or should I only load these when I encounter a problem that one of them is needed to fix? Also, what order should I load them in?

Comment: Wait a couple months and it won't be at all necessary :)

Comment: @yo' and what is coming in a few months?

Comment: @m0nhawk I suppose that sooner or later, the two packages key functions will be incorporated in the `pdflatex` format. (However, Joseph and David have much better insight)

Comment: @yo' Not into the _engine_ rather into the LaTeX2e _format_

Comment: @yo' The format, you mean? I wasn't aware it was still being updated on that scale, considering LaTeX3 is inching closer.

Comment: @SeanAllred shoving off couple inches from several miles `:D` _/sarcasm_ You should watch [David Carlisle: Fixing LaTeX2e](http://vimeo.com/113430065).

Comment: @SeanAllred Read the blog post :-) There is a need for some changes to keep things working: this is all code that is in use anyway, it's a question of trying to put it in the right places.

Comment: [Link for the lazy (or those unaware that Joseph keeps a blog)](http://www.texdev.net/2014/12/28/fixing-latex2e/).  It's on my reading list for tonight! :)

Comment: @SeanAllred It is also the first link in my question.

Comment: @Canageek Whoops! So it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as of a CTAN check on 01/11/2016, here's what I uncovered...

their record for fixltx2e package says:

> This pack­age does noth­ing other than is­sue a warn­ing in cur­rent
>   LATEX Re­leases. In ear­lier re­leases it was used to dis­tribute bug
>   fixes and im­prove­ments to the LATEX ker­nel. See the la­texre­lease
>   pack­age for fur­ther de­tails of the new bug fix pol­icy.
>   https://www.ctan.org/topic/obsolete

and for etex it says:

> An ex­tended ver­sion of TEX (which is ca­pa­ble of run­ning as if it
>   were TEX un­mod­i­fied). E-TEX has been spec­i­fied by the LATEX team
>   as the en­gine for the de­vel­op­ment of LATEX 2e, in the im­me­di­ate
>   fu­ture; as a re­sult, LATEX pro­gram­mers may (in all cur­rent TEX
>   dis­tri­bu­tions) as­sume e-TEX func­tion­al­ity. Devel­op­ment
>   ver­sions of e-TEX are to be found in the TEX live source
>   repos­i­tory.

and for etex-pkg, there is a "Version 2.5 2016-01-07" out now.  The readme file only says:

> The package provides a straightforward interface to many of the
>   extensions  offered by e-TeX; in particular, it modifies LaTeX's
>   register  allocation macros to make use of the extended register
>   range. Note that for LaTeX releases from 2015 onwards, this package is
>   not required to use the extended register range.

Answer (score 19):

Loading the `etex` package should be safe in almost every case. It's main aim is to alter the allocation scheme to use the extra space made available by the e-TeX, and it does this in such a way as to avoid as far as possible any conflict. (Note that the team plan to enable use of the extended registers in a format release but this will use a subtly different approach to the `etex` package.) As to whether you need to load `etex`: only if you find yourself running out of registers. The idea here in adding to the format is that this will free both package authors and end users from worrying about this.

Loading `fixltx2e` is a bit more tricky, and indeed the team are working to ensure that this can be 'backed out' of the format once it is built in as standard. The changes in `fixltx2e` are not currently in `latex.ltx` as they in some way change behaviour. Some of that is nowadays not too much of an issue: for example, making `\(` and `\)` robust uses two additional csnames, which could not go into the format when the issue came up (at the time this could have pushed some people's documents over the edge in terms of name use). Other changes in `fixltx2e` may alter existing documents in some way, and that is more tricky. (For archiving reasons, some documents cannot have any changes at all in output.) That said the content of `fixltx2e` is all stuff that arguably *should* have been in the format when released in 1994.  As noted in [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222149), it's quite possible never to run into a need for `fixltx2e`. As to whether you should load the package: I'd argue 'yes' as these are things that really should be fixed. However, in many cases you might not notice the difference.

That brings us to the question of why the team are looking to add the functionality here to the standard kernel. In the `etex` case, neither users nor package authors really should have to worry about enabling an extended allocation scheme. The format should have some 'awareness' of the capabilities available and use them. In terms of `fixltx2e`, as already noted this is stuff that should have been in the kernel anyway. What adding it will bring is that users won't have to know about the cases where it's useful and package authors should be able to predict more readily the form of certain commands (for patching). There will be a mechanism to reverse this inclusion: there are a few cases where the fixes alter outcomes rather than avoiding out-and-out error, and those are important for the archival stability side of things.

Comment: So, if I don't care about backwards compatibility (I'm writing new documents, not altering old ones), I might as well just copy and past fixltx2e into each document. e-TeX I could, but since I'll probably never need it, I might as well not worry about it as LaTeX will tell me if I do. 

Also: I did hit one of the non-robust things once, which is when I first heard of it.

Answer (score 12):

These packages serve different purposes.  `fixltx2e` corrects some design errors of LaTeX2e; if these errors bother you, you should use it.  They rarely bothered me - I think I encountered them no more than two or three times in my work.

On the other hand `etex` helps to use the additional features of etex engine;  as a user you probably do not need them anyway - unless you, for example, want to define several hundred counters.  Class and package designers need them more often;  I found I must load them for some of my classes.  On the other hand, `etex` produces an (admittedly small) overhead, so I usually do not load it unless I need it.  Anyway, if you use a class or package that needs these features, the designer probably already loaded it.  The only scenario when a user must load `etex` explicitly is when she has several packages each heavily using TeX resources, but still working without `etex` separately.  Then the total may exceed the limit.

Comment: In terms of 'overhead' for `etex` are you thinking of the additional tokens to be skipped in the test for a free register? That is _very_ small in terms of any real document.

Comment: I agree, but some of my machines are oversized smartphones,  see https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-2/tb104veytsman-pad.pdf.  I have a habit to save cycles.