# Weird warning about fixltx2e on beamer

Tags: beamer, luatex, fixltx2e

I'm doing a presentation at beamer (after Powerdot showed its limitations) but I just found an unusual warning (for me) would not let me compile and refers to a package that I don't use directly, but that could be invoked through a third package.

The package in question is `fixltx2e`. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames,x11names,table,handout]{beamer}

\usetheme{Hannover}
%\usecolortheme[named=Turquoise]{structure}

\usepackage[single=false,macros=false,xspace=false]{acro} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchLowercase}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\setsansfont{SourceSansPro} 
\setmonofont{SourceCodePro} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[spanish=mexican,csdisplay=true]{csquotes} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{array,multirow,multicol,rotating,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs} 
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcommand\hd[1]{%
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}} %shortcut from David Carlisle 
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx} 
\sisetup{
output-decimal-marker = {.},
group-minimum-digits = 4,
range-units = single,
list-final-separator = { \translate{and} },
list-pair-separator = { \translate{and} },
%range-phrase = { \translate{to (numerical range)} },
range-phrase={\,a\,}
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\providetranslation [ to = Spanish ]
{ to~(numerical~range) } { a }%substitute the right word here
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\setcellgapes{1.5pt}
\usepackage{hyperrref}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,spanish,textsize=footnotesize]{todonotes}

\author{Me}
\title[SAES]{Strategic analysis of the energy system}
\date{\today}
\subject{Strategic Analysis}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{About us}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Organization}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam...
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Method}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Personal note}
A note...
\end{frame}

\section{Consequences}

\subsection{Economics}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Macroeconomics}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Microeconomics}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
\end{frame}

\subsection
\frametitle{Politics}

\begin{slide}{Subordination}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

I never used before the package `fixltx2e`, at least never directly. I included all my packages from my real preamble. Perhaps few (or many) of the packages for tables won't be necessary, since I actually include a couple of tables and not so large to fit on a frame. But perhaps that package is called from another package, I don't know.

This is the first time I work with `beamer` and `lualatex` together, I think it isn't a problem.

I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248794/textsubscript-not-working-anymore-after-update) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222142/should-i-load-etex-and-or-fixltx2e-by-default) about it. But since I never used that package before, the answers were not useful to me.

I see the `.log` file header about it to dispel doubts about that packages and mine for this file starts as:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238)  (format=lualatex 2015.10.5)  14 OCT 2015 17:22
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**Presentacja.tex
(./Presentacja.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 1
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamer.cls
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasercs.sty
Package: beamerbasercs 2015/03/08 (rcs-revision 368aa9ba9d38)
)
Document Class: beamer 2015/01/05 3.36 A class for typesetting presentations (rc
s-revision 8a39122e1f63)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemodes.sty
Package: beamerbasemodes 2013/09/03 (rcs-revision 768f2d98ca64)
\beamer@tempbox=\box26
\beamer@tempcount=\count79
\c@beamerpauses=\count80
```

I updated `texlive`for last time yesterday. Any idea about it?

Comment: This is surely not a MWE. `fixltx2e` is obsolete with TL2015

Comment: Actually you shouldn't need `fixltx2e` any longer, since its features are now in the latex core, however, this might differ for lualatex

Comment: @ChristianHupfer but I never used directly that package before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of `luatextra`:

> The `luatextra` package loads essential and useful packages for LuaLaTeX. It is meant as convenience for users who don’t want to load them individually.

The packages loaded are `fontspec`, `luacode`, `metalogo`, `fixltx2e`, `luatexbase` and `lualibs`.

So the warning you get about `fixltx2e` is from this package, but it's innocuous.

The errors you get are because

1. `hyperrref` is wrongly spelled
2. `\subsection` has no argument
3. `\frametitle` should be inside a `frame` environment
4. the `slide` environment is only in `powerdot`.

Here's a reformatted version of your preamble. It's better to have, whenever possible, all packages at the top and customization afterwards.

I removed some useless calls and fixed the loading order.

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames,x11names,table,handout]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage[single=false,macros=false,xspace=false]{acro} 
\usepackage[spanish=mexican,csdisplay=true]{csquotes} 
\usepackage{array,multirow,multicol,rotating,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs} 
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx} 
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,spanish,textsize=footnotesize]{todonotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usetheme{Hannover}
%\usecolortheme[named=Turquoise]{structure}

\setsansfont{SourceSansPro} 
\setmonofont{SourceCodePro} 

\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\newcommand\hd[1]{%
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}} %shortcut from David Carlisle 

\sisetup{
  output-decimal-marker = {.},
  group-minimum-digits = 4,
  range-units = single,
  list-final-separator = { \translate{and} },
  list-pair-separator = { \translate{and} },
  %range-phrase = { \translate{to (numerical range)} },
  range-phrase={\,a\,}
}

\providetranslation [ to = Spanish ]
  { to (numerical range) } { a }%substitute the right word here

\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\setcellgapes{1.5pt}

\author{Me}
\title[SAES]{Strategic analysis of the energy system}
\date{\today}
\subject{Strategic Analysis}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{About us}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Organization}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam...
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Method}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Personal note}
A note...
\end{frame}

\section{Consequences}

\subsection{Economics}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Macroeconomics}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Microeconomics}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```